# choose a number from a range based on percentage of another number

Tags: javascript, math

I want to select a number between two numbers depends on the percentage of an input. lets say the range is between 40-60. and input range is between 1-10. if the input value is 10 , the output should be 60. value = 1 , output = 40. value = 5 , output = 50.

I am first trying to figure the algorithm, how to begin with

so far I have used various different formulas.
In general, to scale your variable x into a range [a,b] you can use:

```
normalized = ((b−a)x−min(x))(max(x)−min(x))+a
```

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/281165

Comment: What happens if the input range is 1-10 but the range is 40-45? When the input is 5 will you return 42.5? Or 42 or 43?

Comment: Think about to map each of your both ranges to a unit-interval [0...1] and back. The rest should be easy. (In a second step you can think about how to do the same only with integer arithmedic to avoid any rounding-errors)

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You have the linear transformation equation; this is not really an "algorithm", merely an equation.  You haven't posted any coding attempt, so there's no problem to fix there.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: @GregoryWitek 42.5

Comment: @Prune at equation formation

Comment: I don't understand -- you *have* the transformation equation.  You left out a couple of symbols, but that's all.  Even if you didn't have it, it's a straightforward on-line look-up.  What gives you trouble there?

Comment: The term for this is "interpolation"?

Answer (score 2):

So, a higher-order function might be useful here:

```js
const func = (outMin, outMax, inMin, inMax) => 
             v => outMin + (outMax - outMin) * (v - inMin) / (inMax - inMin);

const boundFunc = func(40, 60, 1, 10);

const v1 = boundFunc(1); //40
const v2 = boundFunc(5); //48.8888....
const v3 = boundFunc(10); //60

console.log(v1, v2, v3);
```

Comment: Thanks bro the function is almost generating the expected result. I got the basics idea. again thanks